# What do I do if sphinx is completely inaccurate?

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

Edit for clarity: **The output I get from sphinx is not even close to the actual words in my sound file. What do I need to do to make it more accurate?**

[Here's the file](https://www.mediafire.com/?l1a6dz896tfgu26) I'm trying to get a transcript from. It should be at a sample rate of 8K.

- Acoustic model I'm using: [en-us-8khz.tar.gz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Acoustic%20Model/)
- Dictionary: [dictionary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/master/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic).
- Language model: [US English Generic](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Language%20Model/)

The speech in the file is "What should you do if you experience a problem with your iPod", but 
as output, I get:

```
<s> <sil> well how how [um] [cough] [um] old [cough] [noise] [cough] <sil> [noise]
[um] <sil> [um] <sil> [uh] [cough] [noise] [cough] [um]
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.test.sphinxtest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("models/acousticmodel/en-us-8khz");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("dictionary/cmudict-0.6d");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/languagemodel/en-us.lm");
        configuration.setSampleRate(8000);
        try {
            StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
            recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("speech/speech8k.wav"));
            System.out.println("Starting recognition");
            SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
            System.out.println("Stopping recognition");
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            System.out.println("number of words " + result.getWords().size());
            for(int i=0;i<result.getWords().size();i++){
                System.out.println(result.getWords().get(i).getWord());
            }       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this page:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor

And I saw that I had to set my audio file to be single-channel.

After I did that, I got a reasonable output.